# Enterprise Library for database connections for different servers

Tags: asp.net, enterprise-library

Hi I am developing an ASP.NET web application. How to connection to database depanding on server using Enterprise Library?

Example: If I am in test environment database should connect to test server connection string. If I am in production environment database should connection to production server connection string.

What is best approach to implement this ?

Comment: Typically this is handled through your configuration file, `web.config`.  Look into the `<connectionStrings>` section.

Comment: But how to know which connection string to take ?

Comment: You would have a separate `web.config` file for each environment, i.e., a `web.production.config` and `web.debug.config`.  The test environment uses the test config, and the production environment uses the production config.  There are lots of solutions out there (including built-in support in Visual Studio) to handle selecting the correct config for publishing, etc.

Comment: Also for completeness, Enterprise Library also supports environmental overrides for configuration.  See [Scenario 7: Managing Configuration in Different Deployment Environments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff953193(v=pandp.50).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the extension called [Slow Cheetah - XML Transforms](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5/)

This package enables you to transform your app.config or any other XML file based on the build configuration. It also adds additional tooling to help you create XML transforms.